# Qweb Report Template Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, qweb

How can I display a field when printing an invoice from sales and hiding it if the report is printed from accounting? Is there any way to access the active module from qweb template? Something similar to the following code:

```xml
<template id="report_invoice_document" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="replace">
        <div t-if="o.active_module == account" class="page">
                <!-- Hide Here -->
        </div>
        <div t-else="" class="page">
                <!-- Show Here -->
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: You could try to use the user groups. Maybe the sales user doesn't have accounting user groups. So try out `o.env.user.has_group('account.group_account_user')`.

Comment: And i don't think there is a chance to find out which module or root menu was used in context of report printing.

Comment: how can you print invoice from sales?

Comment: At the moment in both sales and accounting the same invoice is printed with the same fields, but I need to print only some fields in accounting. The code I show above is just an example but it does not work.

Comment: update your context with active model while rendering report form script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom report or override the existing report with your custom report. Evaluate the active model in the python code and pass an argument to your report for qweb evaluation. You could pass an argument to your qweb just like the one you suggested and then use the exact same logic you used in your suggested code.

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class YourReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.your_addon.report_template_id'

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        _logger.info("RUNNING REPORT")
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('your_addon.report_template_id')
        docs = self.env.context.get('active_ids')   
        docargs = {
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'active_model': self.env.context.get('active_model'),
            'docs': docs,
        }
        return report_obj.render('your_addon.report_template_id', docargs)
```